# Логаут для пользователя если неактивная или закрытая вкладка браузера

Tags: javascript, php

Ребят, помогите решить проблему.
Пользователь проходит авторизацию и этим кодом:

```php
$us_ses_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$extra_time_online = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time() + 60 * 5);
$finish_time_online = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time() + 60 * 30);
$stmt = $pdo->query("UPDATE users SET status_online = '1', extra_time_online = '$extra_time_online', finish_time_online = '$finish_time_online' WHERE id = $us_ses_id");
```

в бд меняю статус онлайна и записываю время finish_time_online при достижении которого, с условием, что сессия не пустая, то обновляю это время еще на 30 мин, а если сессия пустая, то логаут для пользователя. Эта проверка происходит в файле который подключается на всех страницах сайта.
На extra_time_online не обращайте внимания)
Так вот когда неактивная или закрытая вкладка браузера, т.е. страница не обновляется, то проверка на время и сессию:

```
$us_ses_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$start_time = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
$extra_time = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time() + 60 * 5);
$finish_time = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time() + 60 * 30);
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $us_ses_id");
while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
$GLOBALS['get_finish_time_online'] = $result['finish_time_online'];
$GLOBALS['get_extra_time_online'] = $result['extra_time_online'];
}
if ($start_time >= $get_extra_time_online && !empty($us_ses_id)) {
$stmt = $pdo->query("UPDATE users SET extra_time_online = '$extra_time' WHERE id = $us_ses_id");
}
if ($start_time >= $get_finish_time_online && !empty($us_ses_id)) 
{
$stmt = $pdo->query("UPDATE users SET extra_time_online = '$extra_time', finish_time_online = '$finish_time' WHERE id = $us_ses_id");
}
```

по сути, бесполезный кусок кода.
Поэтому нужно проверять состояние вкладки браузера и если реальное время больше чем finish_time_online с бд, а вкладка браузера неактивная/закрытая, то редирект на logout.php.
В js не знаток, а здесь без него точно никак..
Больше всего мне не понятно как проверить состояние вкладки браузера..
Помогите решить задачу.

Comment: обычными словами объясните, чего добавиться то хотите? чтобы пользователь, у которого открытая часавми вкладка не разлогинировался и поддерживал сессию, или чтобы число юзеров онлайн считалось как то само, или что вообще? Статус пользовьтаеля в оффлайн в базе переводить по истечении установленного времени? дак по расписанию запускайте общий скрипт, который это сделает одним запросом для всех

Comment: "по расписанию запускайте общий скрипт" а вот это хорошая идея) совсем вылетело из головы существование такой возможности...

Answer (score 1):

У объекта window есть событие onblur - пользователь закрыл вкладку
И onfocus - пользователь, соответственно, открыл вкладку

```js
window.onblur = function() {
  thisTitle = document.title;
  document.title = 'Ушёл, падла:)';
}
window.onfocus = function() {
  document.title = thisTitle;
}
```